# Annotate over a field of intermediate model django

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset

I have the following scheme:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Task(models.Model):
    pass

class Contest(models.Model):
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField('Task',
                               related_name='contests',
                               blank=True,
                               through='ContestTaskRelationship')

    participants = models.ManyToManyField('User',
                                      related_name='contests_participated',
                                      blank=True,
                                      through='ContestParticipantRelationship')

class ContestTaskRelationship(models.Model):
    contest = models.ForeignKey('Contest', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.ForeignKey('Task', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cost = models.IntegerField()


class ContestParticipantRelationship(models.Model):
    contest = models.ForeignKey('Contest', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.ForeignKey('Task', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='contests_participants_relationship')
    is_solved = models.BooleanField()
```

Now I get the `contest` object and need to fetch all tasks over the `tasks` field, rach annotated with count of users solved it. So, I need to count the number of `ContestParticipantRelationship` with needed `task`, needed `contest` and `is_solved` set to True. How to make such a query?

Comment: Can a `User` solve a task *multiple* times?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Nope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Value, Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Cast, Coalesce


Task.objects.filter(
    contests__contest=some_contest,
).annotate(
    nsolved=Cast(Coalesce(
        Sum('contests_participants_relationship__is_solved'), Value(0)
    ),IntegerField())
)
```

So here we first filter on the fact that the contest of the task is `some_contest`. And next we perform a `Sum(..)` over the `is_solved` column. Since there are corner-cases where this can be `NULL` (in case there is no user that made an attempt, etc.), then we convert it to a `0`, and furthermore we cast it to an `IntegerField`, since otherwise some instances might be annotated with `True`, and `False` in case zero or one user solves it.

Comment: Won't it iterate over all participants of contest, summing booleans? I was looking for a solution with some filtering and then counting

Comment: @NikitinRoman: well since every user can solve it at most once, for every user, there is thus at most one boolean set to true. The filter-count approach will destroy all tasks where no user managed to solve it. So the `0`s would not occur in the result.

Comment: And in SQL booleans do not exist at all: `TRUE` is an alias for `1`, and `FALSE` for `0`. In Python booleans do exist, but these are subclasses of integers (where again there such `True-1/False-0` analogy).

Comment: My point is, won't it be faster if some filtering is done before aggregation?

Comment: @NikitinRoman: well that depends on the filtering. Typically if no indexes are present. filtering should be slower, since this breaks chaining, and thus can result in signifcant slowdowns. But like said, it depends on whether an index is in place, since depending on what indexes, the counting does not per se neds enumerating at all.